# Why isn't Turkey finding Western vendors to purchase SAM systems?

Tags: turkey, nato, weapons

Recently, Turkey has agreed with Russia to [buy S-400 missile](http://www.businessinsider.com/turkey-agreed-to-buy-russias-s-400-missle-system-concerns-about-nato-2017-7?IR=T) system.

Previously, Turkey's [talk with Eurosam failed](http://www.aljazeera.com/blogs/middleeast/2017/06/400-turkey-mission-boost-air-missile-defence-170613161920586.html) apparently because they were reluctant to enter co-production ([see, p-22/32](http://setav.org/en/assets/uploads/2017/04/Analysis_26.pdf)).

Are they reluctant to share sensitive technology with Turkey? If YES, why?

Is that distrust? If YES, why?

Comment: Turkey of late hasn't exactly been a model of democracy, nor has it been a very stable country.

Comment: Also, Russia has a real problem with cash flow and hard currency, now that they lost a lot of oil and gas sales to Europe. My guess is, Russia made a real deal on that S400 system to make the sale and get the cash. Interesting, as Russia and Turkey were getting close to conflict not too long ago, when the Turks shot down a Russian plane that strayed over their airspace from Syria.

Comment: Which is your source to the claim that Western countries do not want to sell SAM systems to Turkey? Couldn't it just be that the Turkey prefered the Russian system, for whatever reason (they think it is better, or cheaper, or fits them better, or whatever)? In fact, in none of your links there is a mention to the claim, and that would be a very important omission if Western countries had decided to cancel their offers...

Comment: @SJuan76, have you read the articles which I linked? The second one clearly says Turkey was in talks with Eurosam, and then the other one says that the talk failed. Also, see this: http://www.aljazeera.com/blogs/middleeast/2017/06/400-turkey-mission-boost-air-missile-defence-170613161920586.html

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy, really? Then why is it still a part of NATO? Why hasn't NATO kicked it out yet?

Comment: Because, as an answer to one of your recent questions put it, an orangutan is at the helm. Also, [realpolitik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realpolitik) is still a thing.

Comment: What was the price and capabilities of both systems?

Comment: I see no indication in your sources that France refused to sell the Aster 30 system to Turkey. There are a bunch of other reasons why talks about arms deal fail, with any country.

Comment: @Relaxed,  http://setav.org/en/assets/uploads/2017/04/Analysis_26.pdf   see P-22/32.

Comment: @anonymous: out of curiosity, what type of answer besides the obvious "because a quasi-dictator is at the helm and we don't like him as much as the Saudis because they've no oil" are you hoping for?

Comment: @anonymous Apart from the bit about UAV and the US Congress, I only see disagreements about technology transfer, it's a common problem but stems from industrial strategy concerns, not any concerns about Turkey specifically. Basically, the more technology you transfer, the less repeat business and economic benefits you can expect, because most of the money is spent locally and the country might even build and export the next generation on its own.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy You said that already but it's not very convincing. Turkey is still extremely stable and as far as dictatorship go, it's far from the worse of those to which France or others have been prepared to sell advanced military tech over the years. Turkey is in the news because it was a much better place 10 years ago, is very close to Europe and as an EU candidate it's held to a higher standard.

Comment: @Relaxed, doesn't make much sense. Coz, previously, we saw that European companies sold Maglev and Highspeed train technologies to China even though there were risks of the company going bankrupt. Some of them even went bankrupt later.

Comment: @Relaxed: Turkey was making headlines in Europe along the lines of "dawn of democracy" just a few days ago in [France](http://cartooningforpeace.blog.lemonde.fr/2017/07/18/turquie-une-dictature-en-marche/), [the UK](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2017/jul/19/turkey-erdogan-turkish-democracy), and [Germany](http://www.spiegel.de/lebenundlernen/job/ngos-in-der-tuerkei-wenn-wir-bibbern-haben-wir-unseren-job-verfehlt-a-1158566.html), owing to the failed coup and the purge that followed from a year ago, and limits on the press. I've no idea what rock you're living under...

Comment: @anonymous How does that not make sense? I can also name a few arms deal with very extensive technology transfer but that does not mean France and others are not reluctant, every contract is different and if they can help it, they will try to avoid it.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Don't you mean sunset? I am fully aware of that and I just explained why I think that is. Still does not contradict my point. For that means there was a democracy to begin with. Meanwhile, we happily sell stuff to dictatorships where there isn't even an opposition to oppress or a fledgling democracy to threaten. You're watching too much TV, this kind of things is not enough to change long-term strategic considerations or trump major interests. Speaking about France specifically, remember that we were delivering police gear to Ben Ali in the days before he fell from power.

Comment: @Relaxed - Yes, I meant sunset. I don't own a TV. And France (or other world powers) selling weapons to no-name no-drama not-in-the-spotlight dictators has nothing to do with Turkey - a contender to entering the EU with a multi-year long history of oppressing opposition and free speech, and the highest number of lost cases (France being second) in the European Court of Human Rights.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Isn't that what I just said? France will indeed make noise about Turkey because it's held to a higher standard as a fledgling democracy and EU candidate, no argument about that. I still don't think the concern will extend as far as threatening arms deals. Besides, you just conceded it was more about optics than simply Turkey turning into a dictatorship, directly contradicting your earlier comments. That, in itself, explains nothing.

Comment: I see that there is not a single mention of Western weapons providers refusing/being forbidden to sign the deal. **Nothing in your links support your claims so far**; whatever you **imagine** are the reasons for the purchase of the Russian system does not count much.

Answer (score 5):

Military export deals fail all the time, there is a long way from publicized talks to an actual purchase. And there are always multiple bids or offers on the table. The industry is also keen on spinning any bit of positive news and you will hear about many many deals that will fall apart down the line, some of them simply because there is no agreement on price. And if you think it has anything to do with Turkey being somehow controversial for the French industry, I can easily name export contracts with Switzerland or Germany that failed very close to the end of the negotiations!

Another issue that's more specific to this industry is technology transfer: In a typical export contract, part of the gear will be manufactured locally in the destination country and the exporting country will train local workers, provide design documents, etc. In all likelihood, that's what the reference to “co-production” is about and if there was any sort of principled reluctance from the French cabinet (as opposed to diverging economic interests), you wouldn't read in the next sentence that Thales and MBDA are still talking with Turkey to put another deal in place.

Technology transfer also means that a big share of the added value and the economic benefits end up in the destination country rather than the source country, which is why it's always contentious. And if you give away too much of your intellectual property, you run the risk of your customer-partner turning into a competitor in a few years time. That issue is always bitterly discussed and can make any deal fail.

Importantly, from all the sources you presented, apart from a vote in the US Congress, I see no indication that there is any specific reluctance to sell to Turkey, just the usual defense industry business. The only newsworthy aspect is that instead of biting the bullet and taking a relatively bad deal, Turkey choose to snub NATO allies and buy Russian stuff. But I do not see any sign that Turkey is having any trouble finding western countries ready to do business with it, at least if they were ready to pay a premium and eschew technology transfer.